# ASP.Net Problem in Prod/Dev

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am facing strange problem,
Whenever I commented second **if** condition, it works in Production, but fail in development.

And when I dont comments second if condtion of code, it works for development and fail for production.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                lblDocument.Text = "Document :" + this.Request.QueryString["A_No"].ToString();
                //if (!frmViewer.Action.Contains("?"))
                //{
                //    frmViewer.Action = String.Format("{0}?A_No={1}&A_Format={2}",
                //                                     frmViewer.Action,
                                                     //this.Request.QueryString["A_No"].ToString(),
//                                                     //this.Request.QueryString["A_Format"].ToString());
//                }
            }
        }
```

Here is Error message:

**CS0117: 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm' does not contain a definition for 'Action'**

Comment: When it fails, what error message is it giving?

Comment: it gives:

CS0117: 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm' does not contain a definition for 'Action'

Comment: Right Click on the solution > Click Clean Solution then Build Solution

Comment: @Barbaros: Yes it works for me...
Thanks you man...
Really appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well **Barbaros Alp** give me following hint to solve this problem...

**Right Click on the solution > Click Clean Solution then Build Solution –**

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify that your ASPX file was migrated up to production with the latest changes?

It looks to me that the Action control was added in development, and the DLL file migrated up to production, but not the corresponding ASPX file.

Comment: I just check production environment, also check the date of each file. It is same.

Answer (score 0):

Other people [that have reported this problem](http://fader.co.uk/post/Action-is-not-a-member-of-SystemWebUIHtmlControlsHtmlForm.aspx) have downloaded the .NET 3.5 SP1 Update, and that fixed their issue.

Make sure both production and development are running the latest version of the .NET Framework (currently the version listed above).

Also, make sure you 'clean' your solution, then rebuild it.